# How to watch a DVD from only files off the DVD

Tags: video, dvd, windows-media-center, windows-media-player, media

A while ago I copied a DVD from disk to my hard drive.  Instead of doing an image copy and writing an .iso file, it copied the file structure from the disk to a folder on my HDD.  That folder contains AUDIO_TS and VIDEO_TS folders, exactly as they appear if I open an actual disk in Windows Explorer to view files.  How can I watch this movie without writing the files to a new disk?  If I have to write a new disk, how do I ensure the disk is playable as a DVD, and doesn't just emerge a file system data disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC will allow you to open the directory and treat it as the filesystem normally found on a DVD (since that's what it is).

Answer (score 1):

The [KMPlayer](http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/) is another choice that you can use to watch the .vob files that were created from the dvd copy.